# Unable to Autowire brave.Tracer inside Spring boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, zipkin

I am working on Spring boot application and I tried to Autowire Tracer object to get the traceId, but its raised the following exception. why??

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'brave.Tracer' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I used the Tracer in a lot of projects and its always working with no issues!!

Comment: We can not tell the exact cause by seeing this error so please show us what you done so far

Comment: I have the same issue having uprev'd from Spring Cloud Greenwich.SR2 to Hoxton.SR1 (which seems to have uprev'd brave from 5.6.5 to 5.9.0.

Answer (score -1):

Spring boot container is not able to resolve the implementation of your autowired interface in this case. Please annotate your implementation class with spring stereotype annotations.

For e.g We provide @Reposiory for dao classes, @Service for service classes & @Component as a generic one. This will solve your problem. If you still face any issues, Just share your code snippet.

[image]